# Unexpected data about function GraphDistanceMatrix

Tags: graphics, matrix, graphs-and-networks

[image: Graph]

This is a weighted undirected graph generated from Excel table data.

```
DATA=Import["MathData/xx.xlsx"][[1]]//IntegerPart;
edgelist=UndirectedEdge[#1,#2]&@@@ DATA
edgew=#3&@@@ DATA
G=Graph[edgelist,EdgeWeight->edgew,VertexLabels->"Name",EdgeLabels->"EdgeWeight"]
WAdj=WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[G]
GraphDistanceMatrix[G] // MatrixForm
```

This is part of the result of GraphDistanceMatrix:

[image: This is part of the result of GraphDistanceMatrix]

I want to get a shortest distance matrix. Official documentation shows that GraphDistanceMatrix returns the shortest distance matrix, but it is clearly not the case. For example, FindShortestPath[G,5,1], the result is {5,4,2,1}, then the distance should be 910, and 630 is given. I don't know what matrix this is.
Am I using something wrong or is this not the shortest distance matrix? Is there a way to get the shortest distance matrix?

Comment: what does `VertexList[G]` give?

Comment: {1,2,3,4,21,47,5,19,6,7,8,18,9,15,10,11,12,14,13,34,26,16,17,27,25,20,24,22,23,44,45,48,29,30,28,31,42,43,32,36,50,33,35,37,39,40,38,41,46,49}
Should it return {1,2,3,4,5,6,...,49,,50}? How do I set it up? The weights of the edges in the Excel table are not given in order.

Comment: Mertin, for this vertex list, the entry in row 5 and column 1 of the `GraphDistanceMatrix` is the distance between vertex 21 and vertex 1 (That is,`GraphDistance[G, 21, 1]` should give 630.) To get the distance between vertex `5` and vertex `1` you need to look at the row corresponding to the position of `5` in `VertexList[G]`, that is, row 7.  I posted an answer explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First an example graph to replicate the *issue*:

```
SeedRandom[123]
rg = RandomGraph[{10, 14}];
edges = EdgeList[rg];
ew = Thread[edges -> RandomChoice[Range[10, 100, 10], EdgeCount@rg]];

g1 = Graph[edges, EdgeWeight -> ew, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexStyle -> White, 
  VertexSize -> Medium, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
FindShortestPath[g1, 5, 1]
```

> ```
> {5, 10, 4, 1}
> ```

```
GraphDistance[g1, 5, 1]
```

> ```
> 140.
> ```

```
gdm1 = Round@GraphDistanceMatrix[g1];

MatrixForm[MapAt[Style[#, Blue, Bold] &, gdm1, {5, 1}]]
```

[image]

As stated [GraphDistanceMatrix >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphDistanceMatrix.html)

[image]

the `ith` row (column) in `gdm1` corresponds not to vertex `i` but to the vertex in the `ith` position in `VertexList[g1]`:

```
VertexList[g1]
```

> {1, 3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 6, 8, 10, 5}

If we add the row and column labels to `gdm1`

```
MatrixForm[MapAt[Style[#, Blue, Bold] &, gdm1, {5, 1}], 
 TableHeadings -> {VertexList[g1], VertexList[g1]}]
```

[image]

we see that the entry showing the shortest distance between `5` and `1` is at the last row and first column.

To get `GraphDistanceMatrix` where the entry `{i,j}` gives the distance between vertices `i` and `j` you can re-order the rows and columns of the matrix using `Ordering[VertexList @ g1]`:

```
ordering = Ordering[VertexList@g1];

MatrixForm[MapAt[Style[#, Blue, Bold] &, gdm1[[ordering, ordering]], {5, 1}], 
 TableHeadings -> {Sort@VertexList[g1], Sort@VertexList[g1]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can  use the first argument of `Graph` to specify the vertex list so that the row/column indices of `GraphDistanceMatrix` coincide with the vertex list:

```
g2 = Graph[Range[VertexCount[rg]], edges,
  EdgeWeight -> ew, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexStyle -> White, 
  VertexSize -> Medium, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  VertexCoordinates -> Thread[VertexList[g1] -> GraphEmbedding[g1]]]
```

[image]

```
gdm2 = Round@GraphDistanceMatrix[g2];

MatrixForm[MapAt[Style[#, Blue, Bold] &, gdm2, {5, 1}], 
 TableHeadings -> {VertexList[g2], VertexList[g2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: awesome thanks so much!